# How to query a table in the database and copy it's data into one one?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am so lost in this situation and badly need a help. The case is this. I copy a data value from a table, let say table book_book
So i use:

```
INSERT INTO book_copy(name,qty,price,year,isbn)
    SELECT bb.name,bb.qty,bb.price,bb.total,bb.year
    FROM book_book bb WHERE ss.name = 'sample PR' and ss.isbn = 'PH019BN'
```

what the output showed me was:

```
name       |   qty      |    price    | year     |  isbn
sample PR  |    4       |             |          |  PH019BN
sample PR  |            |     20.00   |          |  PH019BN
sample PR  |            |             |    1991  |  PH019BN
```

but i what i want is to view it as:

```
name       |   qty      |    price    | year     |  isbn
sample PR  |   4        |     20.00   | 1991     |  PH019BN
```

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: Please show the input for your example

Comment: Here is a free tip: comment out the insert part of the statement to check what the select statement returns. Also, it seems like the data in your book_book table might be a bit messy.

Comment: Is ss.name = 'sample PR' a typo?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i am using postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "pivoting".  From your example data, it looks like `name` and `isbn` are always filled in, and `qty`, `price`, and `year` in one row only.  You can pivot that like:

```
SELECT name, max(qty), min(price), avg(year), isbn
FROM book_book bb 
WHERE name = 'sample PR' and isbn = 'PH019BN'
GROUP BY name, isbn
```

Comment: I am not so sure max function will solve it but in case that that a book qty is filled such as like this:
name           |    qty

sample PR  |    5

sample PR  |    3

then i will display the qty as 8.

Comment: `max` would pick the highest `qty` in the group. Since I'm assuming there's only one row where `qty` is known, that will give you the `qty` for the group. You could also use `min` or `avg` for the same purpose.

Comment: What if the qty is also filled, then how to get the sum of the two?

Comment: You could use `sum(qty)` if multiple rows have a non-empty `qty`. Note that this wouldn't make sense for the year column.

Comment: Oh thank you sir, that works! A combination of sum of group by and sum. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do SUM on rows which has NULL values. because the result will be a NULL, anything added to NULL will result in NULL.

Example : select sum(10+NULL+NULL) from dual will result in NULL.

you can try the below , if there are multiple rows with qty column being NOT NULL it works by adding them all:

```
SELECT bb.name, 
(SELECT SUM(qty) FROM BOOK_BOOK s WHERE s.name = bb.name 
AND s.isbn = bb.isbn and s.qty IS NOT NULL) as QTY ,
(SELECT SUM(price) FROM BOOK_BOOK p WHERE p.name = bb.name 
AND p.isbn = bb.isbn and p.price IS NOT NULL) as price,
(SELECT MAX(year) FROM BOOK_BOOK y WHERE y.name = bb.name 
AND y.isbn = bb.isbn and y.year IS NOT NULL) as year
FROM BOOK_BOOK bb WHERE bb.name = 'sample PR' AND bb.isbn = 'PH019BN'
```

Comment: Thanks sir for additional info.

Comment: The `+` operator propagates `null`, but `sum` does not. `select sum(x) from (select 1 as x from dual union all select null from dual) y` returns 1. Excluding rows with a `null` qty from a `sum` has no effect.